# Understanding this graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

The function is given as $f(x)=2x+3x^\left(2/3\right)$.  The enclosed graph is from wolfram.[image].

My question is why doesn't $f(-1)=1$ show up to the left of the y axis.  I don't see why the domain of this graph is $x>=0.$

Answer (score 1):

First off, the source of the confusion is that WolframAlpha uses the [principal root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Complex_numbers) so that 
$$(-1)^{2/3} = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i,$$
as you can see like so: [`(-1)^(2/3)`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(2%2F3)).

This is in *no way* an error on the part of WolframAlpha (as indicated in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969788/understanding-this-graph/2969792#comment6130424_2969792) on [Jose's otherwise reasonable answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969788/understanding-this-graph/2969792#2969792)) but it is a simple design decision.

There are two simple ways to trigger the use of the real root, if you desire.

### Getting the real root with a link

If you make your screenshot just a little bit larger, you see the following:

[image]

Notice that there is a link that allows you to "use the real-valued root". When you press that, you generate the graph that you expect:

[image]

### Getting the real root with `cbrt`

If you know that you want to use the real root, you can use `cbrt` to denote that from the outset. Thus, [`cbrt(-1)^2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cbrt(-1)%5E2) returns $1$, as you expect and [`2x+3cbrt(x)^2`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2B3cbrt(x)%5E2) gives the graph that you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you write $x^{\frac23}$, what you have in mind is (I suppose) $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$. Yes, this is defined for every real number and it is another real number.

However, many computing systems “think” that$$x^{\frac23}=e^{\frac23\ln x}.$$ Since there are no (real) logarithms of negative real numbers, this ledas to a proble, which is reflected in the picture that you posted here.

Comment: Wow. So is the graph on WolframAlpha incorrect?

Comment: Yes. It is clear that there is also the part of the graph for which $x<0$.

Comment: @user163862 *No*, the WolframAlpha graph is emphatically *not* incorrect.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I disagree. The graphic is not the graphic of the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=2x+3x^{\frac23}$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right - but WolframAlpha doesn't assume that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. I do know what I'm talking about here; I personally wrote the code that produces this graph. [Here is my blog post](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/04/26/get-real-with-wolframalpha-computing-roots/) describing how WolframAlpha deals with roots.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to justify calling this a mistake by WolframAlpha - it is a simple design decision to use the complex root by default and there are two simple ways to trigger the real root, if that is desired.